# Check whether a value in dataframe contains a string from a list of string

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code to iterate over row and column of data frame so check if their value contains a special string then add a new column and categorize it.

```
mylist_bus = ["AAG","BOS"]
mylist_rail = ["BDW","FB"]


scenarios = [df_1,df_2]

keys = [df1,df2]


for key, scenario in zip(keys,scenarios):
    for i, row in scenario.iterrows():
 
        if scenario.loc[i, "ActivityType_" + key] == "leg":
            if scenario.loc[i, "lineId_" + key].str.contains('|'.join(mylist_bus):
                scenario.loc[i,"category_" + key] = "bus"

            if scenario.loc[i, "lineId_" + key].str.contains('|'.join(mylist_rail)):
                scenario.loc[i, "lineId_" + key] = "rail"
       
     elif scenario.loc[i, "ActivityType_" + key] == "car":
                scenario.loc[i,"category_" + key] = "car"
            
df1.head()
```

however, I have the error:

'str' object has no attribute 'str'

in line

```
if scenario.loc[i, "lineId_" + key].str.contains('|'.join(mylist_bus)):
```

how should I check it then?

as an example, part of input data is:

[image]

and I want to have the following output data:

[image]

Comment: Can u include some sample input & expected output.

Comment: @Sushanth I have added the input data and the expected ouput

Comment: @Datanovice it iterates over the list, but I am iterating over the row and columns

Comment: Please include input and expected output as text, so one could easily reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.contains()` is a `String` method in Java

In Python, use `in` or `str.find()`. `in` returns a boolean, while `str.find()` returns the index of the search term, or -1 if not present.
The line that throws an error would become:

```py
if '|'.join(mylist_bus) in scenario.loc[i, "lineId_" + key]:
```

or

```py
if str.find(scenario.loc[i, "lineId_" + key], '|'.join(mylist_bus)) >= 0:
```

Comment: please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62598915/join-is-not-working-for-a-list-of-string-with-more-that-one-item