# '|'.join is not working for a list of string with more that one item

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following list of strings and the code:

```
mylist_bus = ["AAG","BOS","Ext"]
df.loc[df['lineId_EOD'].str.contains('AAG')]
```

with the following results:

```
ActivityType_EOD    lineId_EOD
leg                 AAG_line7
leg                 AAG_line50
```

Then I want to add one more column for these specific values:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if '|'.join(mylist_bus) in df.loc[i, "lineId_EOD"]:
            df.loc[i,"category_EOD"] = "bus"
        
df.loc[df["lineId_EOD"].str.contains('AAG')]
```

However, the result is the same as before, and nothing changes:

```
ActivityType_EOD    lineId_EOD
leg                 AAG_line7
leg                 AAG_line50
```

when I reduce the list  to just one String, for example:

```
mylist_bus = ["AAG"]
```

then it works fine and I have the results:

```
ActivityType_EOD    lineId_EOD  category_EOD
leg                 AAG_line7   bus
leg                 AAG_line50  bus
```

but I need to have a list of more than one string.

Comment: Doesn't look like you're entering the "if" statement within your for loop. The result of `'|'.join(mylist_bus)` with your original list will be ""AAG|BOS|Ext" and this string does not appear to be in your dataframe column `df["lineId_EOD"]`. It's interpreting as a literal not as the "or" statement that you intend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `any` and a generator:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if any(x in df.loc[i, "lineId_EOD"] for x in mylist_bus):
            df.loc[i,"category_EOD"] = "bus"
```

Answer (score 1):

`Series.str.contains` defualts to `regex=True`. That is, the following two are equivalent:

```
df['lineId_EOD'].str.contains('|'.join(mylist_bus))

(df['lineId_EOD'].str.contains('AAG')
| df['lineId_EOD'].str.contains('BOS')
| df['lineId_EOD'].str.contains('Ext'))
```

But the syntax `substring in string` does not use regex. So when you check:

```
'AAG|BOS|Ext' in 'AAG_line7'
```

the answer is `False` because that substring, with all of it's vertical bars, is not part of `'AAG_line7'`

---

As @anky points out you can drop the `iterrows` and use a `.loc` call  with the Boolean Series created by `Series.str.contains` to set the values

```
df.loc[df["lineId_EOD"].str.contains('|'.join(mylist_bus)), 'category_EOD'] = 'bus'

print(df)
#  ActivityType_EOD  lineId_EOD category_EOD
#0              leg   AAG_line7          bus
#1              leg  AAG_line50          bus
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.contains` and `regex=True` as explained here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

`in` does character matching, which is not what you want.